# NETLOGO: How to use variables from links in "nodes" agent?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make simple investment model. I am using NETLOGO and have network, where nodes are investors and they are connected with links. Each link have variable "trust" which stand for trust between those two nodes (investors). Each investor also have a kind of subjective view on stock price and in each round, the value of this change with a formula. My problem is, that part of this formula I want to use is sum of multiplication of trust with every neighbor (variable trust on links "leaving" node) and neighbors subjective view from last round. And I am a bit lost how to use link variable for agent from which those links are going to another agent. Is there some way? I hope it is clear how i mean it. I am really sorry for my english.

Here is the code:

```
globals [realprice
     alpha
     noise]
directed-link-breed [curved-links curved-link]
breed [investors investor]
curved-links-own [trust]
investors-own [price
           stock]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-patches
  setup-investors
  setup-stocks
  setup-links
  setup-switch-trust
  setup-layout
  setup-alpha
  setup-realprice


end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
end

to setup-investors
  set-default-shape investors "circle"

  create-investors number
  [set color red
    set size 1
    set price random (max-extreme - min-extreme) + min-extreme 
    set label-color green   ]
end

to setup-stocks
  ask n-of numberstock investors [set stock 1]
end


to setup-links
   set-default-shape curved-links "curved link"


  ask investors [create-curved-links-to n-of number2 other investors
               [set color blue
            set trust random 100
            set label trust
            set label-color black ]] 


end


to setup-switch-trust
   ask curved-links
  [ifelse show-trust?
  [set label trust]
  [set label ""]
  ]
end

to setup-switch-price
  ask investors
  [ifelse show-price?
    [set label price]
    [set label ""]
    ]
end

to setup-layout
layout-circle investors (world-width / 2 - 2) 
end

to setup-alpha
  ask turtles [set alpha (numberalpha)]
end

to setup-realprice
  set realprice random (max-extreme2 - min-extreme2) + min-extreme2
  end

to go 
  set realprice random (max-extreme2 - min-extreme2) + min-extreme2
  set noise (1 / (random (100 - 1) + 1))
  ask investors  [set price ((alpha * price) + (1 - alpha)*(realprice + noise))]
  ask investors
  [ifelse show-price?
    [set label price]
    [set label ""]
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual code? It's a lot easier to help you if we can see the code, not just a description of it.

Comment: Yeah, sry, my bad :)

Comment: Here it is

to go 
  set realprice random (max-extreme2 - min-extreme2) + min-extreme2
  set noise (1 / (random (100 - 1) + 1))
  ask investors  [set price ((alpha * price) + (1 - alpha)*(realprice + noise))]
  ask investors
  [ifelse show-price?
    [set label price]
    [set label ""]
    ]
   
  tick

Comment: So far realprice has no procedure, but it will. changing prices work on formula, which i finally use only for one random agent. Rest of them should have this formula ): PRICE(i)(n+1) = alpha*PRICE(i)(n) + (1-alpha)*[SUM of (trust(j)*PRICE(j)(n)]. Where PRICE(i)(n) is price of the agent we trying to get price for in last "round". PRICE (j)(n) means price of neighbors agent (these are connected to agent (i) with links) in last round and trust (j)(n) is variable of links which is connecting agent (i) with agents (j). Hope it is clear. I didntwrite here setup procedures. Post was too long.

Comment: But I can write in here if you want. And now when I think about. Is there some way how to put there variable value of previous tick?

Comment: Code in comments is really hard to read. Please edit your question to include well-formatted code.

Comment: Here is the full code i have so far http://leteckaposta.cz/220266033. Thanks everyone for your help. Much appreciated ;)

Comment: I'm not able to make that link work. You should edit your question to include the parts of your code you want to ask about. (Did you know you can edit and improve your own questions on Stack Overflow?)

Comment: So i edited and put there the whole code i have so far. But most of it is just setuping the model.

Comment: Thanks. Which part of the code shows your best attempt at computing "sum of multiplication of trust with every neighbor (variable trust on links "leaving" node) and neighbors subjective view from last round"? I don't see anything that looks like that.

Comment: There is not. I have no idea how to use variables from link in computing variable for nodes. Thats why I ask how to do it :) Just some advices for primitves i could use would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

For an investor turtle, the "sum of ... trust with every neighbor" is:

```
sum [trust] of my-out-curved-links
```

The primitive I'm using here is: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#my-out-breeds

I think that answers the "how to use link variable for agent from which those links are going to another agent" part of your question.

I'm not sure what the "multiplication... with ... neighbors subjective view from last round" part of your question means. (Perhaps that part would be better as a new, separate question?)

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope this will help. I will try to ask it in new question. Thanks for your recommandations.

Comment: So I still didnt figure how to make it sum of (trust*price of the neigbor agent). I figured how to use variable from last tick, but still not sure, how to do it, so that variable trust is multiplicate by the variable of the right neigbor (i mean i need to multiplicate "trust from link which  connects agent (for wich i compute variable) with neihbor agent" and "the neigbor agent which is connected to agent (for which i compute variable)".

Comment: if I understand correctly what you're asking, it's `sum [trust * [price] of other-end] of my-out-curved-links`. see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other-end